# Vue2 : Handle change events on X number of dropdowns ?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've read examples of how to use v-model on select/option lists... and that solves the issue when you have one dropdown..

My questions arrives, since i have x number of dropdowns (generated based on data returned from my model). It's dynamically generated, and there might be anything from 0 to 4-5 dropdowns or so..

The model doesn't have anything to do with the question here, but here's how i generate the dropdowns :

```
<div v-if="item.FoodProperties">
                            <div v-for="fp in item.FoodProperties" class="col-xs-6">
                                <span>{{ fp.Name }}</span>
                                <select>
                                    <option value="" style="font-size:80%">Velg</option>
                                    <option style="font-size:80%" v-for="itm in fp.FoodPropertyOptions" :value="itm.Id">{{ itm.Name }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

So.. anyone got any experience with this, and can tell me how i can get the selected value from each of the dropdowns?

Comment: You've got an array of selects, so use an array of v-models.

Comment: hmm.. not sure how to @erikguan.  can you show me by code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to bind multiple available option for one field on your model? If so you can use this:

```
<div v-if="item.FoodProperties">
    <div v-for="fp in item.FoodProperties" class="col-xs-6">
        <span>{{ fp.Name }}</span>
        <select v-model="item.FoodProperty">
            <option value="" style="font-size:80%">Velg</option>
            <option style="font-size:80%" v-for="itm in fp.FoodPropertyOptions" :value="itm.Id">{{ itm.Name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edited:
after comment i think this should work:

```
<div v-if="item.FoodProperties">
<div v-for="(fp, index) in item.FoodProperties" class="col-xs-6">
    <span>{{ fp.Name }}</span>
    <select v-model="item.FoodProperty[index]">
        <option value="" style="font-size:80%">Velg</option>
        <option style="font-size:80%" v-for="itm in fp.FoodPropertyOptions" :value="itm.Id">{{ itm.Name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: not exactly:) i want several dropdowns (select) on the same component . for example: one which has color options, one which has size, and another one which has material... problem is that it varies. understand?

Comment: not sure how i create the @change events on dynamic created selects when i have several :) that is a good descripton:)

Comment: Thanks @train_fox :) Will check it later this night, due to complete halloween chaos in 30 minutes with 25 crazy, scary kids :)

Comment: Hmm.. with your example i'm having trouble rendering out the result : Cannot read property 'Styrke' of undefined  (styrke is a FoodProperty.Name).. Any idea ?

Comment: thanx again :) hmmm